# regex automatic article tagging

Tags: ruby, regex, tags

Say I have 500 tags and 100000 blog articles. How to tag these articles efficiently as long as the tag names are found in the text body? I guess regex backreference would be helpful but have not figured out a way to do it. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ruby and just realized method `scan` is exactly what I'm looking for.